# php divide an multi-dimensional array as following

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

please help me with a code.
I need the result become like that conceder "funcionario_id" as a key

1) duplicated "funcionario_id" together in an array

2) each other array that not duplicated become in an separated array

note: this multi-dimensional is dynamic, this example show 4 arrays but can be more than that.

my array is:

```
$total_pedidos = Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 54
        [cliente_id] => 5
        [funcionario_id] => 52
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:19
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 51
        [cliente_id] => 7
        [funcionario_id] => 55
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:28
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 52
        [cliente_id] => 5
        [funcionario_id] => 52
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:32
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 53
        [cliente_id] => 6
        [funcionario_id] => 53
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:36
    )

)
```

and the result should be like that:

## duplicated together

```
 Array (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 54
        [cliente_id] => 5
        [funcionario_id] => 52
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:19
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 52
        [cliente_id] => 5
        [funcionario_id] => 52
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:32
    )
)
```

## separated one

```
Array (
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 51
        [cliente_id] => 7
        [funcionario_id] => 55
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:28
    )
)
```

## separated one

```
 Array (
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pedido_id] => 53
        [cliente_id] => 6
        [funcionario_id] => 53
        [pedido_forma_de_pagto_id] => 2
        [pedido_data_emitir] => 2015-12-16 13:07:36
    )
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($total_pedidos as $total_pedido){
    $new_array[$total_pedido->funcionario_id][] = $total_pedido;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Hope this will help.